# volume continuously fluctuating

Tags: 16.04, gui, volume-control

I have recently installed ubuntu 16.04 and I am facing gui issue.
As visible in attached gif, my PC's volume fluctuating infinitely.
Please suggest how to fix this.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Could be a hardware issue - maybe the external volume buttons / keys are stuck ?

Comment: My keyboard and mouse have no volume controls. Headphones' control is analog so this is not possible.